# How to enter multiple lines of commands from a register?

Tags: vim

How can I execute multiple lines of Vim Ex commands from a register? For example, if I copy some mappings I want to try, how can I execute these lines within the current buffer, from the register I've copied them to?

```
nnoremap <leader>b :tab split<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> ...
...
```

I've tried using `:` followed by `<ctrl-r>"` (assuming the lines are in the unnamed register) to paste the lines in command line mode, followed by hitting `<cr>`. The lines that are pasted appear to be separated by `^M`, as opposed to newlines. The approach does not work.

I've also tried using `q:` to open the command-line window, followed by `<ctrl-r>"`, and then hitting enter, but this only executes the current line, rather than all lines I've pasted.

I could paste the lines into a file, and then source that file, but I am looking for an alternative, more direct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:@"` to run the contents of the default register as an Ex command.

See [`:help :@`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3A%40).